# Android: Layout height in percentage of screen resolution

Tags: android, layout, height

I'm quite new in Android, so it'll probably be a stupid question, but here it goes.

I have a RelativeLayout of Activity. In this layout I have another Layout at bottom of a screen. Sometimes I hide it or make it visible, this matters not. Is it possible to make the another layout's height lets say 27% of total screen height? The idea is to keep the other content, except this layout on screen.

Have anyone tried something like this?

Comment: Do you mean to say you want two parts of your screen - the top being 73% of your screen and the second being 27%?  Or do you mean you want a view that sits inside another view covering the bottom 27% of the entire parent when visible?

Answer (score 24):

`LinearLayout` can handle this via `android:layout_weight`. For example, here is a layout containing three `Button` widgets, taking up 50%, 30%, and 20% of the height, respectively:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/fifty_percent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:text="@string/thirty_percent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:text="@string/twenty_percent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

However, you cannot simply declare that an arbitrary widget at an arbitrary point in your layout file should take up an arbitrary percentage of the screen size. You are welcome to perform that calculation in Java and adjust your widget's `LayoutParams` as necessary, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, is more complexe but useful.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parent_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent_of_bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="27">

       //Add your content here

   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you expand on how this works and why it answers the question?

Comment: You can't use android:layout_weight inside a RelativeLayout so, i used a LinearLayout to make the weignt in proportion inside a relative layout,i found the solution from my code project , so i shared it.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach to the problem.

Comment: Nothing, it's for android friends.